# Applicative instance for functions from same domain to Applicative

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, typeclass

Say I have a data type `A` which is applicative. (For the sake of the example, we can assume `A` is `Identity`).

I now have a new data type that corresponds to the "transformation" from one `A` to another:

```hs
data B a b = B (A a -> A b)
```

I want to define the trivial Applicative instance for `(B a)` that produces a new transformation which applies both arguments of `<*>` to its input and then uses the definition of <*> from the Applicative instance of A.

Formulating this is simple enough:

```
instance Applicative (B a) where
    pure x = B $ const $ pure x

    (B ftrans) <*> (B xtrans) = B fxtrans 
        where fxtrans inp = let fout = ftrans inp
                                xout = xtrans inp
                            in  fout <*> xout
```

However, I have the feeling that there should be a straightforward pointfree way of writing this using the fact that `(-> a)` is an Applicative Functor.

As a sample of what I have in mind, consider my definition of the corresponding Functor instance:

```
instance Functor (B a) where
    fmap f (B xtrans) = B $ (fmap f) <$> xtrans
```

Is there a similarly simple way to define the Applicative instance?

Comment: [DerivingVia](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/deriving_via.html?highlight=derivingvia#extension-DerivingVia): `newtype B a b = B (A a -> A b) deriving (Functor, Applicative, Alternative, Monad, MonadPlus, MonadZip, MonadFix, MonadFail, MonadReader (A a)) via ReaderT (A a) A`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One of the neat facts about `Applicative` is that this class is closed under composition.  You can get the following from [`Data.Functor.Compose`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.1.0/docs/Data-Functor-Compose.html):

```
newtype Compose f g a = Compose { getCompose :: f (g a) }

instance (Functor f, Functor g) => Functor (Compose f g) where
    fmap f (Compose fga) = Compose (fmap (fmap f) fga)

instance (Applicative f, Applicative g) => Applicative (Compose f g) where
    pure a = Compose (pure (pure a))
    Compose f <*> Compose x = Compose $ (<*>) <$> f <*> x
```

The `Applicative` instance for `(->) a`, which you bring up, is this:

```
instance Applicative ((->) r) where
    pure = const
    ff <*> fa = \r -> let f = ff r
                          a = fa r
                      in f a
```

Now, let's expand `Compose ff <*> Compose fa :: Compose ((->) (A a)) A b` (some steps skipped):

```
Compose ff <*> Compose fa
    == Compose $ (<*>) <$> ff <*> fa
    == Compose $ \r -> let f = ff r
                           a = fa r
                       in f <*> a
```

So what you're doing is effectively the composition of `(->) (A a)` and `A`.

Comment: Would it be correct to say that `B a b` in the question is equivalent to `type B a = Compose ((->) (A a)) A`?

Comment: @ChristianConkle: Yes.

Answer (score 7):

This, probably?

```
(B ftrans) <*> (B xtrans) = B ((<*>) <$> ftrans <*> xtrans)
```

Answer (score 2):

To piggy-back on Luis Casillas's answer: If `B` is literally the data type you're working with, you can simply use `Compose ((->) (A a)) A` instead. The data constructor would have type `Compose :: (A a -> A b) -> Compose ((->) (A a)) A b`.

You can also use a type synonym: `type B a = Compose ((->) (A a)) A`.

You can have a lot of fun smooshing functors together with `Compose`, `Product`, `Sum`, and friends.